# How to configure IntelliJ to run a JSP/Servlet and get the response in a browser like in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea

I think that it is a silly question. But, I couldn't figure it out on my own as I am a novice user of Intellij Idea and new to Software development.

In eclipse when I press `ctrl + F11`, the response from a Servlet or JSP automatically will be opened in a browser after running on the server. But in IntelliJ the following is what I see.

> When I press `alt+F2`, I see source code in the browser, but not the
>   response from that JSP.

[image]

> In the project view when I right click on a JSP (I don't see "run on server") :

[image]

So, my question is **How do I configure so that I can directly run(`shift+F10`)  a JSP/Servlet on the server and get the response in a browser like in eclipse?**

Comment: Is your IDE configured to make use of a servlet container like tomcat or jetty? Because ultimately this is where your servlet or webapp would have to be deployed. And all the IDE (or the relevant plugin) does is to abstract away that deployment and make it transparent for you.

Comment: Yes. I am using JBoss.

Comment: Have you checked intellij's [wiki](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_JBoss_AS) on jboss integration, to make sure everything is properly configured?

Comment: I think I have done everything that is described on the wiki.